# Error "Maximum DNS-interactive terms limit (10) exceeded"

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, dns, spf

My problem began a few days ago as I tried setting up an email campaign for my users, it kept going into spam! After posting my email on `email-tester.com`, I realized something was wrong with the SPF record. Now I am a newbie with websites and DNS and all of that. I was able to follow along the tutorials given to me but that was it.

It says the max SPF is 10 yet im at 21 somehow?

http://emailstuff.org/spf/check/borntolistbuild.com

That's a link to my domain search thing. As you can see when you go to DNS it shows over 20!

I tried creating a subdomain and thought maybe that would reset my SPF to 0 or something and also tried deleting all the DNS stuff to reset it (didn't help)

- .com purchased on Godaddy
- Hosting from BlueHost
- Email Preparer is Email Octopus
- Email Sender is Amazon SES

I saw on Google a few others have had this problem, but I am a total newbie and didn't understand what they were saying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is:

1. The SPF standard specifies a maximum of 10 DNS lookups to be used in the resolution of a given SPF policy to prevent abuse/attacks.
2. Bluehost's SPF record is a total turd and you shouldn't include it.

You need to replace your domain's SPF record with something more minimal that covers *only* the addresses that *you* are using to send email, not the entirety of Bluehost and Google's networks.

Comment: So I can just remove everything bluehost related to SPF and still be able to send emails?

Comment: Assuming that you're not sending emails via Bluehost IPs, yes.

Comment: Though if you're sending via SES you'll want to have `include:amazonses.com` in there, which is a nice, tight SPF record. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/spf.html

Comment: OK so I removed the bluehost spf record completely and only have the v=spf1 include:amazonses.com ~all ... Will this be enough?

Answer (score 0):

If you only send email from Google Workspace, enter this SPF record:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

If you use additional email senders, enter the SPF record you created in [Basic setup](https://support.google.com/a/answer/10685031) or in [Advanced setup](https://support.google.com/a/answer/10683907).